# Problem creating Mac Catalyst App Store profile

Tags: macos, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst

I am trying to upload my first Catalyst game to Mac App Store.

After many troubles, I successfully created an entry in Mac App Store, then the last part - during submission, it says that "Profile is not a "Mac Catalyst App Store" profile!

Then I try to create a profile, but during creation - I can't get pass this page "Generate a Provisioning Profile" page, asking to create a certificate. After creating the certificate - (Mac App Distribution) downloaded and double tap - then I go to create the profile again, and yet stuck at the same page. So what shall I do?

PS: is it possible that Mac App Distribution is not the correct certificate? I tried Mac Installer Distribution but the result is the same (asking to create a certificate during creation of profile).

Comment: Have you tried with just "Apple Distribution"? That also replaces the old "iOS Distribution".

Comment: Yes, and don't think this is related to the question.

Comment: I gave up and just use Xcode's automatic code sign for the Mac Catalyst target.

Comment: You mean you can use this to submit to Mac App Store? I can use automatic only for testing.

Comment: Yes Lim, I could submit it to AppStore Connect where the build has been processed successfully and is ready for AppStore submission, which I didn't.

Comment: Hi, I have no problem creating a build using automatic code signing. I have problem generating the profile needed to upload to Mac App Store.

Comment: Xcode's automatic signing will also handle generating the profile for you. I would also like to be able to do manual signing but couldn't figure out how to make everything work in that case.

Comment: Generating the distribution profile? How? If you choose automatic signing, there is only 2 choices: Development and Signed Locally. I need to distribute to Mac App Store, not run locally.

Answer (score 3):

Automatically manage signing, Nope!

Nope! Nope! Nope!

These are the steps to follow.

**Step 1**: manually manage the signing process (for Debug) and use the iOS Bundle Identifier

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**: manually manage the signing process (for Distribution) and use the iOS Bundle Identifier

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3**: create the necessary provisioning profiles for development and for distribution

[image: Step 3]

**Step 4**: provisioning profile for "macOS App Development" of your iPad app (iOS)

[image: Step 4]

**Step 5**: provisioning profile for "macOS App Development" (continuation) Mark the profile type "Mac Catalyst" and select your iOS app (for iPad) identifier

[image: Step 5]

**Step 6**: distribution provisioning profile for "Mac App Store" of your iPad app (iOS)

[image: Step 6]

**Step 7**: provisioning profile for "Mac App Store" (continuation) Mark the profile type "Mac Catalyst" and select your iOS app (for iPad) identifier

[image: Step 7]

**Step 8**: select your iOS app in your "App Store Connect" record, and click "Add macOS App"

[image: Step 8]

**Step 9**: upload screenshots, enter app description, upload the binary file, etc.

[image]

**Step 10**: to upload your iOS app (for Mac), you must select "Any Mac (Intel)" and then, "Product" -> "Archive"

[image: Step 10]

**Step 11**: when archiving process is finished you can distribute your app (iOS) that can run on Mac

[image: Step 11]

**Step 12**: you must enter the provisional profile created previously to distribute your app

[image: Step 12]

IMPORTANT! in this step

**IMPORTANT!**

The distribution profile not appears automatically (by default) as happen with iOS Apps.

You must select the option "DOWNLOAD" and then, appears the 2 profiles:

- Mac (Catalyst) developer profile for your App
- Mac (Catalyst) distribution profile for your App

Select the distribution profile, and that's all!!!

**Step 13**: finally, if you have problems with Mac App Icon (because not appears), please read this answer (my answer) to solve the problem

[My answer to solve Mac Icon problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645178/app-icon-in-itunes-connect-is-missing/64367889#64367889)

Comment: Hi, I follow your advice until step 12 - I can develop and create a Mac Catalyst profile, but in step 12, I can't find the Mac Catalyst profile. If I do an import profile and imported the profile, the Next button is dimmed and cannot continue.

Comment: Yes, that's true! The same thing happened to me. I did not understand anything. But finally I found it. I'll explain (I'll edit the answer and attach a screenshot). I DO NOT know why this happens with the Mac App (Catalyst). The same does NOT happen with the iOS Apps. ATTENTION, the trick: when you click it offers you 2 options, import and download. Select download and 2 profiles will appear, the Mac developer one and the Mac distribution one. Select distribution.