# Upload App Icon option missing in AppStoreConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I could not find option to upload App Icon (1024x1024) on newly updated home screen of https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/
Where I can add the App Icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App Icon in iTunes Connect is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645178/app-icon-in-itunes-connect-is-missing)

Comment: @thedp, that question is different, the accepted answer on that question is no more valid. It is the latest update by AppStoreConnect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, we don't need to upload 1024 icon individually in AppStore, whatever the app icon you uploaded in Xcode project(appicons), will be reflected in AppStore.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays it's added on the Xcode AppIcon Assets, doesn't need to be updated anymore in the appstoreconnect.